# PHP contact form with Gatsby

Tags: php, reactjs, gatsby

I'm creating a Gatsby portfolio and I want to include a PHP contact form. I've seen a lot of examples that use external resources to send the email from the site. An example is '[Getform](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-a-contact-form/#getform)' which is referenced in the Gatsby docs. But I'd prefer to not have to rely on an external resource and keep the PHP script within my project. My question is related to my approach.

I'm using an axios POST request to send the form data to a PHP file located on the same server as my project. These PHP do not live within my project repo. Is this the best approach or is there another way to keep the PHP sendmail file within my Gatsby project, so that when I run the build and deploy everything can be pushed to the server without error. Ideally I'd like the PHP files to live within my project repo also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby generates a [set of static files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/glossary/static-site-generator/). There's no server-side runtime, so you'll need to run your services separately and call them at [client-side runtime](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-fetching/#fetching-data-at-client-side-runtime) using axios, for example, or the fetch browser API.

If you absolutely want a single repo, you can probably run a PHP server and serve the built Gatsby site on a given route. However this is far from a typical use of Gatsby, it goes against [Gatsby's content mesh philosophy](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-core-philosophy/#create-a-cohesive-content-mesh-system), and it will make your release workflow more complicated (and not simpler).

I recommend keeping your services and your Gatsby site separate.

PS: to learn more about the "content mesh", here's a [great 3-part article about it on Gatsby's blog](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2018-10-04-journey-to-the-content-mesh).

Answer (score 5):

You can place your php scripts in /static/api

After the build and deployment you can call it with https://domain.tld/api/scriptname.php

Gatsby move the api directory from the static folder to the root. :)